# SQL CHECK constraint to prevent date overlap

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, date-range

I have a table that describes which software versions were installed on a machine at various times:

```
machine_id::integer, version::text, datefrom::timestamp, dateto::timestamp
```

I'd like to do a constraint to ensure that no date ranges overlap, i.e. it is not possible to have multiple software versions installed on a machine at the same time.

How can this be achieved in SQL? I am using PostgreSQL v8.4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 8.4 this can only be solved with triggers. The trigger will have to check on insert/update that no conflicting rows exist. Because transaction serializability doesn't implement predicate locking you'll have to do the necessary locking by yourself. To do that `SELECT FOR UPDATE` the row in the machines table so that no other transaction could be concurrently inserting data that might conflict.

In PostgreSQL 9.0 there will be a better solution to this, called exclusion constraints (somewhat documented under [CREATE TABLE](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-createtable.html)). That will let you specify a constraint that date ranges must not overlap. Jeff Davis, the author of that feature  has a two part write-up on this: [part 1](http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2009/11/01/temporal-keys-part-1/), [part 2](http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2009/11/08/temporal-keys-part-2/). Depesz also has some [code examples describing the feature](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/01/03/waiting-for-8-5-exclusion-constraints/).

Answer (score 11):

In the meantime (since version 9.2 if I read the manual correctly) postgreSQL has added support for [rangetypes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html).

With those rangetypes the issue suddenly becomes very simple (example copied from the manual):

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    during tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (during WITH &&)
);
```

And that's it. Test (also copied from the manual):

```
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES
    ('[2010-01-01 11:30, 2010-01-01 15:00)');
```

> INSERT 0 1

```
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES
    ('[2010-01-01 14:45, 2010-01-01 15:45)');
```

> ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "reservation_during_excl"
>       DETAIL:  Key (during)=(["2010-01-01 14:45:00","2010-01-01 15:45:00")) conflicts
>       with existing key (during)=(["2010-01-01 11:30:00","2010-01-01 15:00:00")).

Comment: and how would you go about having this EXCLUDE statement for unique rows with a FK, i.e, we have a 

CREATE TABLE reservation (
    resourceId integer NOT NULL,
    during tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (during WITH &&)
);

Comment: @mikejames: Like this: `exclude using gist ( resourceId with =,  during with &&)`

Comment: to use EXCLUDE with scalar values enable: CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist; then, exclude using gist ( resourceId with =,  during with &&)

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason or another you can't change the table schema and need to keep two time rows, you can build the range within the constraint, for example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE reservations (
    datefrom timestamp,
    dateto timestamp,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (tsrange(datefrom, dateto) WITH &&)
);
```

I used tsrange in this case to deal with timestamp types, but there are others you can use - check out the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist; 

CREATE TABLE machines(
    machine_id integer, 
    version text, 
    during tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist ( machine_id with =, during with &&)
);
```

machines with same id in the table will not overlap.

Comment: I get an error on machin_id saying integer needs an operator class... `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) data type integer has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want a CHECK costraint, like mentioned in the title? That is not possible, since CHECK constrains can only work one row at a time. There might be a way to do this using triggers, though...

Comment: Any way of constraining the data will be sufficient. I just (wrongly!) assumed it would be a CHECK...

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Implementation of a CONSTRAINT on non-overlapping datetime ranges
-- , using the Postgres rulesystem.
-- This mechanism should work for 8.4, without needing triggers.(tested on 9.0)
-- We need a shadow-table for the rangesonly to avoid recursion in the rulesystem.
-- This shadow table has a canary variable with a CONSTRAINT (value=0) on it
-- , and on changes to the basetable (that overlap with an existing interval)
-- an attempt is made to modify this variable. (which of course fails)

-- CREATE SCHEMA tmp;
DROP table tmp.dates_shadow CASCADE;
CREATE table tmp.dates_shadow
    ( time_begin timestamp with time zone
    , time_end timestamp with time zone
    , overlap_canary INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' CHECK (overlap_canary=0)
    );
ALTER table tmp.dates_shadow
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (time_begin,time_end)
    ;

DROP table tmp.dates CASCADE;
CREATE table tmp.dates
    ( time_begin timestamp with time zone
    , time_end timestamp with time zone
    , payload varchar
    );

ALTER table tmp.dates
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (time_begin,time_end)
    ;

CREATE RULE dates_i AS
    ON INSERT TO tmp.dates
    DO ALSO (
    -- verify shadow
    UPDATE tmp.dates_shadow ds
        SET overlap_canary= 1
        WHERE (ds.time_begin, ds.time_end)
           OVERLAPS ( NEW.time_begin, NEW.time_end)
        ;
    -- insert shadow
    INSERT INTO tmp.dates_shadow (time_begin,time_end)
        VALUES (NEW.time_begin, NEW.time_end)
        ;
    );

CREATE RULE dates_d AS
    ON DELETE TO tmp.dates
    DO ALSO (
    DELETE FROM tmp.dates_shadow ds
        WHERE ds.time_begin = OLD.time_begin
        AND ds.time_end = OLD.time_end
        ;
    );

CREATE RULE dates_u AS
    ON UPDATE TO tmp.dates
    WHERE NEW.time_begin <> OLD.time_begin
    AND NEW.time_end <> OLD.time_end
    DO ALSO (
    -- delete shadow
    DELETE FROM tmp.dates_shadow ds
        WHERE ds.time_begin = OLD.time_begin
        AND ds.time_end = OLD.time_end
        ;
    -- verify shadow
    UPDATE tmp.dates_shadow ds
        SET overlap_canary= 1
        WHERE (ds.time_begin, ds.time_end)
           OVERLAPS ( NEW.time_begin, NEW.time_end)
        ;
    -- insert shadow
    INSERT INTO tmp.dates_shadow (time_begin,time_end)
        VALUES (NEW.time_begin, NEW.time_end)
        ;
    );


INSERT INTO tmp.dates(time_begin,time_end) VALUES
  ('2011-09-01', '2011-09-10')
, ('2011-09-10', '2011-09-20')
, ('2011-09-20', '2011-09-30')
    ;
SELECT * FROM tmp.dates;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
INSERT INTO tmp.dates(time_begin,time_end) VALUES ('2011-09-30', '2011-10-04')
    ;

INSERT INTO tmp.dates(time_begin,time_end) VALUES ('2011-09-02', '2011-09-04')
    ;

SELECT * FROM tmp.dates;
SELECT * FROM tmp.dates_shadow;
```